# C++ : write a triangle class using point class

Tags: c++, geometry

in c++ I'm trying to create a triangle class using a point class. the correct way in java would be:

```
    public class Point {
    double x, y;

    public Point(double x, double y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }    
    }

public class Triangle {
Point p1,p2,p3;

public Triangle(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3){
    this.p1=p1;
    this.p2=p2;
    this.p3=p3;
}
}
```

in main:

```
Point p1=new Point(0,0);
Point p2=new Point(1,1);
Point p3=new Point(-1,1);
Triangle t1=new Trianle(p1,p2,p3);
```

in c++ I have:

```
class point{
double x1,y1;

public:

       point(double x, double y){
       x1=x;
       y1=y;
       }  

};         

class triangle{
point p1, p2, p3;

public:

       triangle(point varp1, point varp2, point varp3){
       p1=varp1;
       p2=varp2;
       p3=varp3;
       }
};
```

in main:

```
    point p1(-1,1);
    point p2(1,1);
    point p3(0,0);
    triangle t1(p1,p2,p3);
```

somehow this doesnt work, why?
..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? In the way that your class names are in a different language to their constructors?

Comment: Please post your real C++ code and explain exactly what your error is rather than type random stuff at the end of your post to evade the filter.

Comment: The constructors should have the same name as the class. And you should use constructor initialization lists.

Comment: The compiler can't translate German dreieck to triangle.

Comment: constructor name wasnt the problem, i write it in german and overseen one name. the error is "no matching function for call to point:point(). candidates are  point:point(const point&)"

Comment: That is because you are not using constructor initialization lists, so your triangle's points get default constructed. And your point class has no default constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work because the `triangle` constructor will attempt to default construct its `point` members before assigning to them, but `point` doesn't have a default constructor. This is because you provide only a `point` constructor that takes 2 arguments, so the defaulted default constructor is deleted.

Instead, you should use a member initialization list to initialise the points:

```
dreieck(point varp1, point varp2, point varp3)
  : p1(varp1), p2(varp2), p3(varp3)
{ }
```

This initialises each of the members `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` with the arguments `varp1`, `varp2`, and `varp3` respectively, therefore avoiding the default construction.

Comment: thanks for not b*tching at the typos and actually helping. worked!

Comment: @user2302476 I think I was the one who was bitching about the typos. Also, it's not bitching, it's trying to understand your problem.

Comment: @user2302476, being accurate is not "bitching about typos", the compiler is stricter than stackoverflow commenters. If you're a programmer then you need to be accurate. Posting innaccurate or incomplete code is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: I was talking about Mat, who even could't read my notes about where is java code, and where ist c++. bitching is agressive "pointing", if you do it not agressiveley, I hav nothing against it

Answer (score 2):

In C++ member variables are constructed before the body of the constructor and if you don't specify how they should be constructed then they will be default-initialized, so your constructor is equivalent to this

```
 triangle(point varp1, point varp2, point varp3)
 : p1(), p2(), p3()  // <--- default-initialize each member
 {
   p1=varp1;
   p2=varp2;
   p3=varp3;
 }
```

Now it should be obvious that your constructor doesn't create the members as copies of the constructor arguments, it creates them as default-constructed objects then assigns new values to them, and to do that the `point` class needs a default constructor.

The other answers show how to do it correctly: use the member initializer list.  You should do this for the `point` constructor too. Using member initializers is the idiomatic way to construct member variables and base classes in C++, rather than assignment in the constructor body.  For some types of members variables (reference, const objects, and non-DefaultConstructible types) it's the *only* way to initialize member variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your `point` class is not defined (or automatically provided with) a default-constructor. Because you overloaded the constructor, the compiler-generated one was not included. And in your `triangle` class you're default-constructing three objects of type `point`. You'll get an error because there is no default-constructor available.

You should explicitly define your constructor (and you should initialize your members through the *member-initializer list*), for example:

```
class point
{
    public:
        point() : x1(0), y1(0) {}
        ...
};
```

Moreover, if we make your parameritized constructor take *optional* arguments, it can act as a default-constructor. For example:

```
class point
{
    public:
        point(double x = 0, double y = 0) : x1(x), y1(y) {}
        ...
};
```

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, the OP's `triangle` constructor would be improved by using member initializers instead of assignment, and then there's no real need for a default constructor (although adding one may be useful anyway)